# Distinguishing between Laptop Specifications

Tags: ruby, sorting

If I have thousands of string like

> Toshiba - Satellite C855D-S5100 Laptop, AMD E-Series Processor (1.3 GHZ), 4GB DDR3, 320GB HDD, 15.6" Display, AMD Radeon HD 6310, Double-layer DVD±RW/CD-RW, 802.11 b/g/n, Windows 8  » for $279.99 at Best Buy

and have a Laptop object with different properties like:

- Processor
- RAM
- Hard Drive
- Operating System
- etc

I want to create a laptop object for every string and set the attributes with the formatted data from the string.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to go about doing this rather than splitting the string into an array by doing s.split(","), looping through it and comparing it to keywords:

i.e. If the string contains "DDR3", set that string as the RAM property

Comment: There is no easier way than splitting into individual words, or at least into phrases if there is enough consistency in the order of the features. If there is no consistency then you'll have to parse based on manufacturer and maybe even the model. I doubt a regex pattern will be universal across all the manufacturers so be prepared to do the hard work of defining patterns for every model.

Comment: If this is not a task to be performed on a regular basis in real-time environment, I would suggest you to treat an input as kinda “language to parse”. You might want to have a look at lexical parsers implementations. In a couple of words: you create a thesaurus and parse the whole input against it without splitting in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell if for the thousands of strings you have some semblance of regularity, structure. The difficulty of what you ask is dependant of the variability between 2 different entries.

> Toshiba - Satellite C855D-S5100 Laptop, AMD E-Series Processor (1.3
>   GHZ), 4GB DDR3, 320GB HDD, 15.6" Display, AMD Radeon HD 6310,
>   Double-layer DVD±RW/CD-RW, 802.11 b/g/n, Windows 8 » for $279.99 at
>   Best Buy

Is pretty disimilar from

> Apple MacBook Pro - Core i5 2.5 GHz - 500 GB HDD / 5400 rpm - 13.3″
>   1280 x 800 - 4 GB RAM - English

In one you have RAM in the other DDR3. In one you have 4GB with no space and in the other there is a space. But it's not hopeless if your list contains strings which are all very similar in structure. Then I'd say figure out a regex for what you want to extract.

Comment: Unfortunately the data does not have a consistent structure, and I would like the algorithm to be as flexible as possible. Is this not possible to accomplish?

Comment: Forget about finding an easy way to do this. If it were me I would start with regular expressions (learn it by experimenting if I did not already know a bit of it). Then I would tweak one to get ram for a bunch of very different test cases. Rinse/Repeat fot all the spec you want to extract out of those strings. Other than that, look around to find a better more structured (XML, JSON, CVS) datasource. Good luck!